# vue3, style becomes invalid after the page is refreshed

Tags: css, vuejs3, page-refresh

## vue3, style becomes invalid after the page is refreshed

- The normal entry page style is valid
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kQ03.png)
- The style is invalid after the refresh
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyzV9.png)
- Check that styles are actually introduced normally
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRxU0.png)
- Looking at the lifecycle function shows that the component is not destroyed when refreshed

```
  beforeCreate () {
    console.log("beforeCreate")
  },
  created () {
    console.log('created')
  },
  beforeUnmount () {
    console.log('beforeUnmount')
  },
  unmounted () {
    console.log('unMounted')
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5cCn.png)

- code

```
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const store = useStore()

const productId = ref(route.query.productId)
const productInfo = computed(() => store.state.product.selectedProductInfo)

function tabController() {
  // Tabs JS
  $('.tab ul.tabs').addClass('active').find('> li:eq(0)').addClass('current');
  $('.tab ul.tabs li').on('click', function (g) {
    let tab = $(this).closest('.tab'),
      index = $(this).closest('li').index();
    tab.find('ul.tabs > li').removeClass('current');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item').not('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideUp();
    tab.find('.tab_content').find('div.tabs_item:eq(' + index + ')').slideDown();
    g.preventDefault();
  });
}
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted')
  tabController();
  store.dispatch('product/selectProduct', {productId: productId.value})
})

function carouselController() {
  // Product View Slider JS
  let bigImage = $("#big");
  let thumbs = $("#thumbs");
  let syncedSecondary = true;

  bigImage
    .owlCarousel({
      items: 1,
      slideSpeed: 2000,
      nav: true,
      autoplay: true,
      dots: false,
      loop: true,
      responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
      navText: [
        "<i class='ri-arrow-left-line'></i>",
        "<i class='ri-arrow-right-line'></i>",
      ]
    })
    .on("changed.owl.carousel", syncPosition);

  thumbs
    .on("initialized.owl.carousel", function() {
      thumbs
        .find(".owl-item")
        .eq(0)
        .addClass("current");
    })
    .owlCarousel({
      items: 5,
      dots: false,
      nav: false,
      navText: [
        "<i class='ri-arrow-left-line'></i>",
        "<i class='ri-arrow-right-line'></i>",
      ],
      smartSpeed: 200,
      slideSpeed: 500,
      slideBy: 4,
      responsiveRefreshRate: 100
    })
    .on("changed.owl.carousel", syncPosition2);

  function syncPosition(el) {
    //if loop is set to false, then you have to uncomment the next line
    //let current = el.item.index;

    //to disable loop, comment this block
    let count = el.item.count - 1;
    let current = Math.round(el.item.index - el.item.count / 2 - 0.5);

    if (current < 0) {
      current = count;
    }
    if (current > count) {
      current = 0;
    }

    //to this
    thumbs
      .find(".owl-item")
      .removeClass("current")
      .eq(current)
      .addClass("current");
    let onscreen = thumbs.find(".owl-item.active").length - 1;
    let start = thumbs
      .find(".owl-item.active")
      .first()
      .index();
    let end = thumbs
      .find(".owl-item.active")
      .last()
      .index();

    if (current > end) {
      thumbs.data("owl.carousel").to(current, 100, true);
    }
    if (current < start) {
      thumbs.data("owl.carousel").to(current - onscreen, 100, true);
    }
  }
  function syncPosition2(el) {
    if (syncedSecondary) {
      let number = el.item.index;
      bigImage.data("owl.carousel").to(number, 100, true);
    }
  }
  thumbs.on("click", ".owl-item", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let number = $(this).index();
    bigImage.data("owl.carousel").to(number, 300, true);
  });
}
watch(productInfo, (value) => {
  if (value) {
    console.log('productDetail, productInfo change')
    nextTick(() => carouselController());
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import url(@/styles/css/boyi/productDetail/productDetail.css);
</style>
```

- `mounted()` call `store` to get data. the data is prepared in advance, not from server
- use `for in productInfo.imageList` get image url for carousel component, and `carouselController()` set `javascript`

Comment: There's too much to parse, but it's clear at a glance that there's way too much DOM manipulation, which shows a lack of Vue fundamentals.  The important thing to know is, Vue _manages_ the DOM.  When you take control of the DOM yourself and manipulate elements, you take control away from Vue, and that's when reactivity and other things break (unless you're extremely careful or doing very simple things).  I don't know exactly what is wrong with your code, but IMO it should be completely refactored with Vue best practices in mind.